# Rails: Multiple "has_many through" for the two same models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Can't wrap my head around this...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fantasies, :through => :fantasizings
  has_many :fantasizings, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Fantasy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :fantasizings
  has_many :fantasizings, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Fantasizing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fantasy
end
```

... which works fine for my primary relationship, in that a `User` can ***have*** many `Fantasies`, and that a `Fantasy` can ***belong*** to many `Users`.

However, I need to add another relationship for ***liking*** (as in, a `User` "likes" a `Fantasy` rather than "has" it... think of Facebook and how you can "like" a wall-post, even though it doesn't "belong" to you... in fact, the Facebook example is almost exactly what I'm aiming for).

I gathered that I should make another association, but I'm kinda confused as to how I might use it, or if this is even the right approach. I started by adding the following:

```
class Fantasy < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :users, :through => :approvals
  has_many :approvals, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :fantasies, :through => :approvals
  has_many :approvals, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Approval < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :fantasy
end
```

... but how do I create the association through `Approval` rather than through `Fantasizing`?

If someone could set me straight on this, I'd be much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your first set of code, then in your User Model add:

```
has_many :approved_fantasies, :through => :fantasizings, :source => :fantasy, :conditions => "fantasizings.is_approved = 1"
```

In your Fantasizing table, add an is_approved boolean field.

Comment: Call me dull, but I'm not sure I follow what you're doing here. Could you explain a little bit more so I can understand this? Thanks!

Comment: The line of code I posted does the same exact thing as "has_many :fantasies, :through => :fantasizings" except that it checks your fantasizings table for an is_approved boolean.  So User.fantasies lists all fantasies, User.approved_fantasies lists all fantasies that have been approved.

Comment: Played around with it and I think I got the gist of it. Thanks.